# Drop down menu over image

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, carousel

Not sure how to go about this, I guess its more of a proof of concept. I have a bootstrap carousel that has several images that scroll, the images are products. My client saw something on a website and wanted to know if its possible. My question is how would I go about it, where in my html or CSS would I input, the drop down menu on the images that scroll.

Here is my carousel
http://modernstudiotest.jbglobal.net/slider_menu.html

And here is the website, where the menu happens, basically you 
point your mouse cursor to the top and a white menu falls down.
https://www.specialized.com/us/en/

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
         interval: 0
     })
    });
```

```css
    @charset "UTF-8";
    /* CSS Document */
    
    .carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
        background-image: none
    }
    
    .carousel {
        margin-bottom: 0;
     padding: 0 40px 30px 40px;
    }
    /* Reposition the controls slightly */
    .carousel-control {
     left: -12px;
    }
    .carousel-control.right {
     right: -12px;
    }
    /* Changes the position of the indicators */
    .carousel-indicators {
     right: 50%;
     top: auto;
     bottom: 0px;
     margin-right: -19px;
    }
    /* Changes the colour of the indicators */
    .carousel-indicators li {
     background: #c0c0c0;
    }
    .carousel-indicators .active {
    background: #000000;
    }
    
    .well {
    background: #ffffff
    }
    
    .thumbnail {  
    border-style: none;
    }
    
    .col-mid-12 {  
    border-style: none;
    }
    
    .carousel-control {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%; /* pushes the icon in the middle of the height */
    z-index: 5;
    display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
             <div class="well"> 
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
                     
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                     
                    <!-- Carousel items -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        
                    <div class="item active">
                     <div class="row-fluid">
                       <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_1a.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;" /></a></div>
                       <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_1b.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;" /></a></div>
                       <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_1c.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;" /></a></div>
                       <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_1d.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;" /></a></div>
                           <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_1e.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;" /></a></div>
                     </div><!--/row-fluid-->
                    </div><!--/item-->
                     
                    <div class="item">
                     <div class="row-fluid">
                      <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_2a.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;" /></a></div>
                       <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_2b.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;" /></a></div>
                       <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_2c.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;" /></a></div>
                       <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_2d.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;" /></a></div>
                           <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_2e.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;" /></a></div>
                     </div><!--/row-fluid-->
                    </div><!--/item-->
                     
                    <div class="item">
                     <div class="row-fluid">
                      <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_3a.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;" /></a></div>
                       <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_3b.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;" /></a></div>
                       <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_3c.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;" /></a></div>
                       <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_3d.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;" /></a></div>
                           <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_3e.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;" /></a></div>
                     </div><!--/row-fluid-->
                    </div><!--/item-->
                     
                    </div><!--/carousel-inner-->
                     
                    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
         <span>
                 <img src="img/ms_Lft_arrow.png" />
                </span>
         
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
         <span>
                 <img src="img/ms_rt_arrow.png" />
                </span>
      </a></a>
                    </div><!--/myCarousel-->
                     
                </div><!--/well-->   
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Hopefully someone understands and maybe can help me or point me in the right directions, Thanks.

Comment: You can check this link:-http://codepen.io/arjunamgain/pen/siLfq

Answer (score -1):

to show the menu over the top of your image carousel, put your new top menu code to above the `myCarousel` and it's position should be `absolute` with `z-index` greater than 1 and `width:100%`.

Also, don't forgot to add `relative` position to the `well` class div.

please see below code -

+Add below CSS -

```
    /* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

And Edited HTML -

```
<html><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Slider_menu</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/ms_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 0
    })
});
</script>


</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="well" style="position:relative"> 

  <!-- Your Menu code will be here -->
  <div class="dropdown" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20;">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
                </ol>

                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                      <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_1a.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;"></a></div>
                      <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_1b.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;"></a></div>
                      <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_1c.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;"></a></div>
                      <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_1d.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;"></a></div>
                       <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_1e.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;"></a></div>
                    </div><!--/row-fluid-->
                </div><!--/item-->

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_2a.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;"></a></div>
                      <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_2b.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;"></a></div>
                      <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_2c.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;"></a></div>
                      <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_2d.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;"></a></div>
                       <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_2e.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;"></a></div>
                    </div><!--/row-fluid-->
                </div><!--/item-->

                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_3a.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;"></a></div>
                      <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_3b.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;"></a></div>
                      <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_3c.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;"></a></div>
                      <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_3d.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;"></a></div>
                       <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/middle_slider_3e.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:125%;"></a></div>
                    </div><!--/row-fluid-->
                </div><!--/item-->

                </div><!--/carousel-inner-->

                <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span>
             <img src="img/ms_Lft_arrow.png">
            </span>

    </a><a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span>
             <img src="img/ms_rt_arrow.png">
            </span>
  </a>
                </div><!--/myCarousel-->

            </div><!--/well-->   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>


</body></html>
```